# How Join 2 mp3 file after one end

Tags: php, audio

I am 2 mp3 file 
audio_a.mp3
audio_b.mp3

i want to join two mp3 at one mp3 file. affter join two file frist play audio_a.mp3 then play audio_b.mp3.

How i do it on php ?

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can't do that in PHP alone. At least not if you want the new mp3 to be able to play. Do some research and find some command line tool that you can call from PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do in PHP, Possible in Javascript..  use javascript `onended` Event to trigger another..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 
 Song will be started automatically....
<audio id="song1" autoplay>
  <source src="https://freemusicdownloads.world/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Justin-Bieber-Sorry-PURPOSE-The-Movement.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<audio id="song2">
  <source src="https://freemusicdownloads.world/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Justin-Bieber-Love-Yourself-PURPOSE-The-Movement.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>


<script>
var aud = document.getElementById("song1");
aud.onended = function() {
  document.getElementById("song2").play();
};
</script>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: We have no idea if the OP want's to play the songs online or not or if they want to be able to download the result. The question is simply way to vague and unspecific to be answered.

Comment: if it not posible on php .so that i want to straming all audio file in folder order by file uploded time. how do it ? plz help

Comment: You can order in 2 ways..  first method is make Database record to save audio info like name, path, time while uploading then filter and order from database by uploaded time. Next method is scan the audio path and get files info then sort by time.